# How to change a default expression in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

by default, zabbix comes with the following expression that alerts you when the server's disk is less than 5GB of free space

```
{Zabbix server:vfs.fs.size[/,pused].last()}>{$VFS.FS.PUSED.MAX.CRIT:"/"} and
(({Zabbix server:vfs.fs.size[/,total].last()}-{Zabbix server:vfs.fs.size[/,used].last()})<5G or {Zabbix server:vfs.fs.size[/,pused].timeleft(1h,,100)}<1d)
```

I want to know if there is a way to change these 5GB to a slightly larger number, like 20Gb for example

I am new to Zabbix and any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: So change `5G` to `20G`?

Comment: as it is a default rule, Zabbix doesn’t let you edit and I didn’t find a way to do that

Comment: You can edit it, normaly. The gui is really intuitive, but maybe you should spend some time learning what are templates and autodecting items and how they work. You want to edit the template or the single host? If the host, duplicate the item and edit. If the template, go to the autodectiong rule and edit it there.

Comment: If you're having really problems, post a screenshot how you can't edi tit. Ther should be "detected by: " that you can click on, and below there should be "Update" and "Duplicate" so you can duplicate the trigger. But, anyway, this is not a programming problem per se - maybe you should consider posting on zabbix forum next time.

Comment: like i said, i'm new using zabbix, things that are obvious to everyone for me it's not yet, but anyway, i appreciate the tips!

Comment: You can't edit the host trigger because it's templated. You can edit the template and all the linked hosts will be updated. If you need different sizes on different hosts, use a User Macro.